# How to set allowed origin to request host in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, ruby-on-rails-5

I am writing an application with a couple of APIs that should be accessible from any host. Now, so far I have handled this in my `application.rb` in the following way:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
}
```

However, one of the clients that accesses the API doesn't allow to get data from sources where `'*'` is defined. My idea was to set the allowed origin dynamically to the one that requests the API. Something like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins ActionDispatch::Request.headers['Host']

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

But since `cors.rb` is an initializer, it doesn't have access to the requests that come in. Is there a way to make the origins list dynamic, so it will always just include the request host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply do this with a `before_action` within your controller.

```
class ApiBaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cors_headers

  private

  def set_cors_headers
    response.set_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin
  end

  def origin
    request.headers["Origin"] || "*"
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

And if you do this ?

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    # this proc should return true or false
    origins { |source, env| true }
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: %i[get post put patch delete options head]
  end
end
```

Comment: Will this just set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or will it set the value as the request origin?